# Как удалить файлы по ключевому слову во всех директориях через терминал

Tags: terminal

всем привет, в репозитории есть куча ненужных файлов с определенным расширением, лежат они в разных директориях, какая команда в терминале пробежится по всем директориям и удалит ненужные файлы? файлы mac сам насоздавал с расширением .DS_Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

удалить все файлы по заданному расширению рекурсивно

```
find . -name "*.DS_Store" -exec rm {} \;  -print
```

или так

```
find . -name "*.DS_Store" -delete
```

Comment: все сработало, только как сделать, чтобы файлы удалялись без запроса подтверждения?

Comment: после rm добавьте " -f "

Comment: огромное спасибо